# Problems with flask app with apache server

Tags: apache-httpd, webserver, lubuntu, apache-virtualhost

Just created a simple flask app that returns the string "hello world", it works and does what expected, If I use my http://localhost/ with the apache server enabled I will get the "hello world" string, the problem comes when I modified the flask_app.py and made a function that needs the info of 2 text files, the code works, if I where to run this app with "flask run" the server works and returns what is expected, but when I run it in the apache server , nothing happens, so I ran the command:
**tail /var/log/apache2/error.log** and got the error:

**[FileNotFoundErr 2] No such file or directory: 'example.txt'**

But the files are in the dir where my project is, if I run the ls command in the my project directory(**/var/www/html/flask_app**) I get:

```
|_flask_app
  |_example.text
  |_example1.text
  |_app.wsgi
  |_wsgi.py
```

So the required files are indeed in the project directory, where should I move those 2 text files or where should I add them for the app to recognize them?

app.wsgi

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/var/www/html/flask_app')
from wsgi import app as aplication
```

Any help apreciated, If you guys need it I can eve post the wsgi.py if it helps.

Thanks!

Comment: Your script is looking for `example.text`, but the file is named `_example.text`?

Comment: no both are called ```example.test```.